# Table in html won't work with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, html-table

May anyone tell me why this won't work? I am trying to show and hide a table in a form to prevent the user accessing certain input elements. Just advice me what to do and what the best practice is. Thank you.
im new to jquery and html:

html and jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#table1').hide();
});

$('input[name="both"]').click(function(){
 $('#table1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="both" />
<label for="walk_in">Walk in</label>
</p>
<form>
<table id="table1" name="table1">
    data1
</table>
<table id="table2" name="table2">
    data2
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: I see tables used like divs here. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

You need to add your table content in   tag..

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#table1').hide();
});

$('input[name="both"]').click(function(){
 $('#table1').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="both" />
<label for="walk_in">Walk in</label>
</p>
<form>
<table id="table1" name="table1">
   <tr><td> data1 </td></tr>
</table>
<table id="table2" name="table2">
  <tr><td>  data2 </td></tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Comment: Your closing `tr`, `td` tags are the wrong way round

Answer (score 0):

I would assign an ID to that input and try to use that to address the element in jQuery:

```
<input type="radio" id="my_input" name="both" />


$('#my_input').click(function(){
 $('#table1').show();
});
```